# Scraping data using Python3 from JS generated content

Tags: web-scraping, python-3.5

I need to scrape a website  (say "www.example.com") from a python3 program which has a form with two elements as follows:

```
1: Textbox
2: Dropdown
```

Need to run queries with several options (e.g. 'abc' and '1') to be filled/selected in the above form and scrape the pages thus generated. The pages thus generated after filling the form and submitting have a url as seen in the browser as "www.example.com/abc/1".The results on this page are fetched through a javacript as can be verified in the page source. Synopsis of the relevant javascript below:

```
<script type="text/rfetchscript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
url: "http://clients.example.com/api/search",
data: JSON.parse('{"textname":"abc", "dropval":"1"}'), 
method: 'POST',
dataType: 'json',
       Logic to fetch the data
</script>
```

I have tried to get the results of the page by using methods of requests, urllib:

1: 
    resp = requests.get('http://www.example.com/abc/1')

2:
    req = urllib.request.Request('http://www.example.com/abc/1')
    x = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    SourceCode = x.read()

3: Also tried scrapy.

But all of the above return only the static data as seen in "view page source", and not the actual results as can be seen in the browser.

Looking for help on the right approach here.

Answer (score 0):

Scraping pages with urllib or requests will only return the page source since it can not execute the javascript codes etc that the server returns. If you want to load the content just like your browsers you have to use selenium with an optional chrome or firefox driver. If you want to keep using urllib or requests you have to find out which content pages the site loads with for example the network tab in your chrome browser. Probably the data you are interested in is loaded from a json file.